# Displaying Multiple GeoJSON polygons using gmplot and Python

Tags: python, geojson

I'm new to Python and learning Python on the fly. I have a geojson file that contains multiple polygons.  I would like to display them all on a Google Map using gmplot. However, I can get one polygon to display but no others. I'm not sure if a function is the right choice, but I'm trying to iterate through and plot each polygon.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

I've been researching online on other tips, but no luck.

```
import json
import numpy as np
import gmplot
from itertools import groupby
import os

tstPolygon = "unit.geojson"

gmap = gmplot.GoogleMapPlotter(45.570312, -110.536931, 13)
gmap.apikey = "##############################"

def coords(newpoly):
    with open(newpoly) as f:
        js = json.load(f)
        for feature in js['features']:
            coordList = feature['geometry']['coordinates']
            name = feature['id']
            xy = coordList[0]
            xy_new = list(zip(*xy))
            x = xy_new[0]
            y = xy_new[1]
            gmap.plot(y,x,color='blue',edge_width=10)
            gmap.draw("mymap.html")

coords(tstPolygon)
```

I hope that the python script will iterate and plot each polygon into the html file.  I was thinking of using a unique 'id' property that is attached to each polygon and utilize groupby(). But unsure how to apply this.